# C# Access denied when creating file on network path directory

Tags: c#, report, filestream, filepath, telerik-reporting

EDIT:
So I've now obtained a service account "docwriter" and password "password" for that network folder. I've created a class ConnectionToNetworkFolder and tried several attempts to try to use this.  But still not successful.
I'm having an issue trying to save a pdf file in my network's path directory but working fine when saving to a local folder.   See bottom of post, I included my class and my page

---

Original Post:
I've tried several codes shown before.  I have also changed the network folder's security permission to add "Network Service" (from online) with access to modify, read&execute, list folder contents, read, write (do I need special permission or full control?).  What am I doing wrong?

***Local Folder: Success

```
            Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor reportProcessor = new ReportProcessor();
            RenderingResult result = reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", instanceReportSource, null);

            string documentName = ProductionInstructionPrintPage.plantCode + ProductionInstructionPrintPage.machine + ProductionInstructionPrintPage.ordNum;
            string filePath = @"C:\Users\Lily\Desktop\SavingPdfTesting";
            string fileName = documentName + "." + result.Extension;
            string full_path = filePath + fileName;

            //writes the pdf to disk
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(full_path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.Write(result.DocumentBytes, 0, result.DocumentBytes.Length);
            }
```

***Network Try 1: Fail - Access denied

```
            Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor reportProcessor = new ReportProcessor();
            RenderingResult result = reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", instanceReportSource, null);

            string documentName = ProductionInstructionPrintPage.plantCode + ProductionInstructionPrintPage.machine + ProductionInstructionPrintPage.ordNum;
            string filePath = @"\\testing.company.com\reports\";
            string fileName = documentName + "." + result.Extension;
            string full_path = filePath + fileName;

            //writes the pdf to disk
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(full_path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.Write(result.DocumentBytes, 0, result.DocumentBytes.Length);
            }
```

************************EDIT******************************************

Here is my ConnectionToNetworkFolder class:

```
class ConnectionToNetworkFolder : IDisposable
    {
        string _networkName;

        public ConnectionToNetworkFolder(string networkName, NetworkCredential credentials)
        {
            _networkName = networkName;


            var netResource = new NetResource()
            {
                Scope = ResourceScope.GlobalNetwork,
                ResourceType = ResourceType.Disk,
                DisplayType = ResourceDisplaytype.Share,
                RemoteName = networkName
            };

            var userName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials.Domain)
                ? credentials.UserName
                : string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", credentials.Domain, credentials.UserName);

            var result = WNetAddConnection2(
                netResource,
                credentials.Password,
                userName,
                0);

            if (result != 0)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(result, "Error connecting to remote share");
            }
        }

        ~ConnectionToNetworkFolder()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            WNetCancelConnection2(_networkName, 0, true);
        }

        [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
        private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NetResource netResource,
            string password, string username, int flags);

        [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
        private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(string name, int flags,
            bool force);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class NetResource
    {
        public ResourceScope Scope;
        public ResourceType ResourceType;
        public ResourceDisplaytype DisplayType;
        public int Usage;
        public string LocalName;
        public string RemoteName;
        public string Comment;
        public string Provider;
    }

    public enum ResourceScope : int
    {
        Connected = 1,
        GlobalNetwork,
        Remembered,
        Recent,
        Context
    };

    public enum ResourceType : int
    {
        Any = 0,
        Disk = 1,
        Print = 2,
        Reserved = 8,
    }

    public enum ResourceDisplaytype : int
    {
        Generic = 0x0,
        Domain = 0x01,
        Server = 0x02,
        Share = 0x03,
        File = 0x04,
        Group = 0x05,
        Network = 0x06,
        Root = 0x07,
        Shareadmin = 0x08,
        Directory = 0x09,
        Tree = 0x0a,
        Ndscontainer = 0x0b
    }
```

my page:
Declaring credential variable:

```
        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"docwriter", "password");
```

function on click event:

```
   private void apprBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
string documentName = Mainpage.apprDate;
            string filePath = @"\\testing.company.com\reports\";
            string fileName = documentName + "." + result.Extension;
            string full_path = filePath + fileName;


            using (new ConnectionToNetworkFolder(filePath, credentials))
            {

                    //writes the pdf to disk
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(full_path, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        fs.Write(result.DocumentBytes, 0, result.DocumentBytes.Length);
                    }

            }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried giving permission to IIS_IUSRS ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the share's permissions. As you stated, you added permissions to 'Network Service', but what is the user running you app?

Comment: okay I've got a assigned a username & password for this network folder. but i don't think I got the coding correct.

I ended up adding a class ConnectionToNetworkFolder class (see above - I edited the initial message with this)
and I think I'm having issues trying to figure out how to use this

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you need to impersonate file access on the server. You may not have sufficient share permissions as you are "writing" to the network.

Here is an example on how to impersonate file / folder access. It clearly explains what you need to do.
[Code Project UNC Access](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43091/Connect-to-a-UNC-Path-with-Credentials)